# (0|10)* regular expression

Tags: regex

what strings are accepted by this expression (0|10)* regular expression? I was thinking 0, 10, and was wondering if it would accept something like 010 since it is an or?

Thanks

Comment: What environment/language are you implementing this pattern in (just out of curiosity)?

Comment: No particular language. Just trying to understand the possible outputs.

Comment: Trying to implement them using DFAs

Comment: Put it into regex101.com, read explanation and you will see what strings will pass the regex check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the `*` at end signifies zero and unlimited times, so it will match an infinite number of strings. However, matches will be broken up by 2 `1`s in a row, or a `1` without a zero before or after it (if your alphabet is only 0 and 1).

Check out some examples [here](https://regex101.com/r/2pacGc/1)

So to answer the specific example in your question, `010` will be matched, as the regex will find `0`, and then `10`.

Comment: Thanks for this! :) So as long as there is a * outside the brackets I can combine them? What if there is no * outside the brackets, they cannot be combined, eg 010?

Comment: If you don't include a star, `010` will still return a match, but it will be 2 matches, one for `0` and one for `10`.  With the star, `010` is a single match.

Comment: So a 010 will not be accepted by a language that accepts L(0|10)?

Comment: @Anony This answer is correct.  Here are some more examples: https://regex101.com/r/k0DV25/1

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

No JavaScript will not accept 010 because it is a or statement:

(0 | 10) is the same as
0 or 10 and so it will only accept 0 and 10

if you want it to also accept 010 then change it into
(0 | 10 | 010)

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is incorrect.  There is a `*` at the end of the regex, that is 0 to unlimited times, `010` will definitely be matched.  Even without the `*` `010` will be matched as 2 different matches.

Comment: Oh yah just noticed that, I recommend chrisz's answer then